# iOS / Xcode: saving datalist ipad

Tags: ios

im new to iOS/xcode app and have a question.

If i make a form with "name" "age" "date now" how/where is it saving the info and how do i make new items ?

Have tried to search google for "xcode saving item to list" but its not what im looking for.
Can someone help me with a link to a tutorial or the name function that i need to look at.

So i can read/learn about
 - save function
 - show the saved items in a list.
 - get one or more saved items to another page/view in the app.

Comment: What kind of form? Web page form? Table view? What language are we even discussing?

Comment: is Xcode not just one language.
The form is with two textfields and a date field in xcode view, where i want to know how and where its saving the submitted field data.
This is not a webpage in HTML5 with fluid, its a real ipad app.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, not a language. I guess you mean Objective-C language. Show the code and at least a screen shot of the interface you have. Include delegate methods for the text fields.

Comment: Hi Wain, thats my point I haven't got any delegate yet, bc. I want to learn to make it, so im looking for a tutorial that explain this, not a working code, so when i have that - then I will get back to Stackoverflow if I need to add more functions.

Comment: Maybe start with delegates (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/) and then look at saving after you understand that then.

Comment: Thx Wain, will u plz. give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to deal with getting notified when the text in each field changes. This is done by using the delegate methods of the text fields (`<UITextFieldDelegate>`). In particular, `textFieldDidEndEditing:` will allow you to grab the text when the edit is complete.

Once you have the text, you need to store it somewhere. This could be in a dictionary, or, if you want to display in a list, it could be in an array.

A dictionary is easier if each of the text fields means something different. Then the keys of the dictionary represent the meaning.

An array is easier if it's just a list of arbitrary text. The issue here is how to know that you haven't got duplicates. In this case it can be better to have a `submit` button which loops over all of the text fields in order and adds the text from each to the array.

Once you have the text in an array or dictionary you can save it to disk (`writeToFile:atomically:`) or use that as the source data for a table view.